# hypen makes the synctex busy (and no pdf output)

Tags: math-mode, pdf, elsarticle, amssymb

I've just moved in a new office and I am using a new computer to compile the .tex files I have prepared (and already compiled!) with my laptop until this morning.

Nevertheless, everytime I try to compile, I got the **synctex.gz** busy and I realized that it only happens when the hypen (or "minus sign") is used in the math mode.
If I take it out, everything runs smoothly.

Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \begin{document}

 \title{\textbf{A wonderful, appealing title}}

 \section{Sample preparation}

 The crystal surface was prepared in the UHV chamber at a base pressure
 of $10^{-9}$ mbar.

 \end{document}
```

If I try to run it, no pdf file is generated.
Here is what is written at the very end of the log file:

> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>   4745 strings out of 494797
>   64879 string characters out of 3171511
>   130437 words of memory out of 3000000
>   8075 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
>   18747 words of font info for 53 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
>   171 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>   40i,4n,37p,855b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
>   !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file txsy): Font txsy at 600 not found
>   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

The problem occurs also if I write the math expression

```
$ -10^{9} $.
```

Whereas, if I type the hypen outside of the math mode, such as :

```
- $10^{9}$
```

or if I do not use it at all, everything works fine.

Has anyone ever had such problem? How do I solve it?
Thank you in advance,

I.

Comment: Compile without errors  on  windows 10  with `texlive 2016`

Comment: Obviously one font is missing. What texsystem are you using?

Comment: Well, the error is *not* produced by the minus sign, but rather from the fact you have an incomplete or buggy TeX distribution. My crystal ball says MiKTeX.

Comment: I updated both the editor and the compiler: I am using MikTeX 2.9 and the latest release of TeXmaker.
I checked the packages and installed every single one I am using on my laptop.

Comment: texlive 2016 can produce the pdf with no problems.
Still wondering where the issue comes from...

Comment: This is the beginning of the log file on the computer which cannot build the pdf 

    "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.9.5) 14 SEP 2016 12:28
entering extended mode
**./myfile.tex
(myfile.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 17 language(s) loaded.
(C:\Users\Ilaria\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\elsarticle\elsarticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd"

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED:
I replaced the whole MixTex folder in the computer with the one from my laptop. 
Then I got a new error "pdftex.def not found".

I installed by hand the  "graphics-def" package and now it is working.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by replacing the miktex folder, as noted in a comment.